# Checking if parent directory is contained within file path

Tags: php

I am working with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and as part of that I would like to exclude certain paths.

The idea I have so far (code below) works ok if I happen to specify an exact match. But I also need to match if a parent matches (i.e. `/foo` would match `/foo/bar`).

I can't quite figure out how to achieve this in a clean manner.

```
// for clarity: $exclDirArray normally comes from function  (function dirIterator($path,array $exclDirArray=array()), I have just split it out to make my example code simpler
$exclDirArray=array('/foo','/bar');
$files = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,\FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS|\FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | \FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO);
foreach(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($files) as $file) {
   if (!empty($exclDirArray) && \in_array($file->getPath(),$exclDirArray)) {
       echo $file->getPath().PHP_EOL;
      continue;
  }
 // more stuff goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `RegexIterator`. Something along the lines of:

```
$rexeg = new RegexIterator($files, '#^((?!/foo).)*$#i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

In this case, `$regex` should be an array of all the paths that don't include the string `/foo`.